# Background Images not rendering in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, background-image

A website I did a while back had this issue come up a few months ago, and I tried to fix it a few times but every attempt has failed, and I have a lot of work on my plate moving forward.

Sometimes when I hover over a part of the background it will render, but white out another area of the website. If I inspect the element in chrome, it shows up right away.

Could anyone help me in tracking this issue down?

http://www.womackband.com

A few notes, using Bootstrap, Font-Awesome, Stellar, and a few other js includes... Also there are some externals being loaded from the widgets being imported from reverb nation.

Thank you for taking a look in advance!

Comment: when I hover over a part of the background it will render, but white out another area of the website.? I am unable to reproduce it

Comment: are you able to re-produce large areas of the background being whited out? That is the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have seen your problem... i am not sure but this is -webkit-background-size:cover issue.
because default background-size:cover is overwrite your -webkit-background-size:cover.

I am not sure but you can try this...I can do but i can't access your file.

add every section id on these attribute:

```
display:block !important;
width:100% !important;
float:left !important;
```

and also do this -webkit-background-size:cover !important;

Thanks

Comment: Added what you had listed to each section, yet the issue still exists. Didn't have any affect negative or positive.

Thank you for suggesting tho!